# Binary Tree in C++/CLI with value is System::String

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, binary-tree

I have a problem when i try to insert node to binary tree. I don't understand why the argument is always null. Here is my program.
file "BinaryTree.h"

```
 #pragma once
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H
#define BINARYTREE_H
using namespace System;
ref class BinaryTree
{
public:
    BinaryTree()
    {
        root = nullptr;
    };
    ~BinaryTree()
    {
        destroySubtree(root);
    };
    void insertNode(String^);
    bool searchNode(String^);
    void remove(String^);
    String^ disPlay()
    {
        return disPlay(root);
    };
private:
    ref struct TreeNode
    {
        String^ values;
        TreeNode ^left;
        TreeNode ^right;

    };
    TreeNode ^root;
    void insert(TreeNode ^, TreeNode ^);
    void deleteNode(String^, TreeNode ^);
    void destroySubtree(TreeNode ^);
    void makeDeletion(TreeNode ^);
    String^ disPlay(TreeNode ^);

};

#endif
```

And here is file "BinaryTree.cpp"

```
    #include "BinaryTree.h"
using namespace System;
void BinaryTree::insert(TreeNode ^node, TreeNode ^newNode)
{
    if (node == nullptr)
        node = newNode;
    else if (newNode->values->CompareTo(node->values)<0)
        insert(node->left, newNode);
    else
        insert(node->right, newNode);
}
void BinaryTree::insertNode(String^ s)
{
    TreeNode ^newNode = gcnew TreeNode;
    newNode->values->Copy(s);
    newNode->left = newNode->right = nullptr;
    insert(root, newNode);
}
bool BinaryTree::searchNode(String^ s)
{
    TreeNode ^node = root;
    while (node)
    {
        if (node->values->CompareTo(s)==0)
            return true;
        else if (node->values->CompareTo(s) > 0)
            node = node->left;
        else
            node = node->right;
    }
    return false;
}
void BinaryTree::remove(String^ s)
{
    deleteNode(s, root);
}
void BinaryTree::deleteNode(String^ s,TreeNode ^node)
{
    if (node->values->CompareTo(s) > 0)
        deleteNode(s, node->left);
    else if (node->values->CompareTo(s) < 0)
        deleteNode(s, node->right);
    else
        makeDeletion(node);
}
void BinaryTree::makeDeletion(TreeNode ^node)
{
    TreeNode ^tempNode;
    if (node == nullptr){}
    else if (node->right == nullptr)
    {
        tempNode = node;
        node = node->left;
        delete tempNode;
    }
    else if (node->left == nullptr)
    {
        tempNode = node;
        node = node->right;
        delete tempNode;
    }
    else
    {
        tempNode = node->right;
        while (node->left)
        {
            tempNode = tempNode->left;
        }
        tempNode->left = node->left;
        tempNode = node;
        node = node->right;
        delete tempNode;
    }
}
void BinaryTree::destroySubtree(TreeNode ^node)
{
    if (node)
    {
        if (node->left)
        {
            destroySubtree(node->left);
        }
        if (node->right)
        {
            destroySubtree(node->right);
        }
        delete node;
    }
}
String^ BinaryTree::disPlay(TreeNode ^node)
{
    String^ s;
    if (node)
    {
        s = node->values;
        return s+=disPlay(node->left);
        return s+=disPlay(node->right);
    }
    return s;
}
```

When I use like this:

```
BinaryTree^ Tree = gcnew BinaryTree();
string key="abc0123456"; 
String^ sss = gcnew String(key.c_str());
Tree->insertNode(sss);
MessageBox::Show(Tree->disPlay());
```

but the result always null,when i check at step "Tree->insertNode(sss);" then the argument "sss" in function "insertNode(String^ s)", it mean variable "s" is null.
What should i do now to fix this problem?
Anyone can help me pls

Comment: String::Copy() does not do what you think it does.  Use `newNode->values = s;` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because String.Copy is static method, I believe. It returns back string which is not assigned to value field anywhere in you code

Something like

```
newNode->values = String::Copy(s);
```

might work

Answer (score 0):

Your disPlay method will not recurse to right branches ever, Because it returns values + left recursion only.

I believe your intentios was something more like this:

```
String BinaryTree::disPlay(TreeNode ^node)
{
    String s;
    if (node)
    {
        s = node->values;
        s+=disPlay(node->left);
        s+=disPlay(node->right);
    }
    return s;
}
```